# Drop tables using table names from a SELECT statement, in SQL (Impala)?

Tags: sql, impala, apache-zeppelin

How do I drop a few tables (e.g. 1 - 3) using the output of a SELECT statement for the table names? This is probably standard SQL, but specifically I'm using Apache Impala SQL accessed via Apache Zeppelin.

So I have a table called tables_to_drop with a single column called "table_name". This will have one to a few entries in it, each with the name of another temporary table that was generated as the result of other processes. As part of my cleanup I need to drop these temporary tables whose names are listed in the "tables_to_drop" table.

Conceptually I was thinking of an SQL command like:

```
DROP TABLE (SELECT table_name FROM tables_to_drop);
```

or:

```
WITH subquery1 AS (SELECT table_name FROM tables_to_drop) DROP TABLE * FROM subquery1;
```

Neither of these work (syntax errors). Any ideas please?

Comment: You can use python script to do it. No direct method possible.

Answer (score 0):

even in standard sql this is not possible to do it the way you showed.
in standard sql usually you can use dynamic sql which impala doesn't support.
however you can write an impala script and run it in impala shell but it's going to be complicated for such task, I would prepare the drop statement using select and run it manually if this is one-time thing:

```
select concat('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ',table_name) dropstatements
from tables_to_drop
```